# Use Promises in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge all object from first to last.But I am facing problem while combining the objects:
here is object:

```
{
    a: 'c',
    b: 'u',
    c: 'd',
    x: () => new Promise((a, r) => setTimeout(() => a('b'), 100)),
    u: () => 'h',
    q: () => 'r'
}, {
    b: 'f',
    c: 'i',
    d: 'e',
    z: () => 'f',
    v: () => {
        return null;
    },
    s: () => 't',
    r: () => 'd',
    o: () => 'd'
}, {
    c: 'y',
    d: 'o',
    f: 's',
    e: function() {
        return this['a'];
    },
    w: () => {
        return;
    },
    t: () => Promise.resolve('a'),
    p: () => new Promise((a, r) => setTimeout(() => a('c'), 10))
}).then(result => console.log(result));
```

here is the requierments:

1.merge objects from first to last (conflicting fields/function should not be overridden)

2. call all functions on merged object in descending order. These functions may return string or Promise (for string) or nothing. Values should be output and processed in the same order.
3. each string is a name of a field or function in merged object and it should be mapped to the value of the field or function result (non-existing should be ignored).
4. these field values should be joined into a resulting string
5. function should return that string as a result

Comment: And what did you tried so far? We wont solve you lesson here.

Comment: The snippet you've posted is a syntax error, there appears to be some code missing in the beginning.

Comment: Is that minified code? If so, could you please post the original?

Comment: "*conflicting fields/function should not be overridden*" - what else should happen to them? For example, what's the expected value of `result.c` - `d`, `i`, `y` or some combination thereof?

Comment: And you can't prevent overriding as soon as you have to pass the intermediate-result to the functions. The same way `function(){ return this["a"] }` read the property it could also have written it `function(){ this.e = this.a }`.